# How to set tag on a Button programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

On the XML I can set my flag on android:tag, but how can I do it pro grammatically?

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:tag="myFlag"/>
```

Comment: `setTag()` function ?

Answer (score 4):

Add an id to the view

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Button"/>
```

In code you can get/set the tag

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
// set tag
button.setTag("myFlag");

// get tag
String tag = (String) button.getTag();
```

Answer (score 3):

To set the Tag for a view call the **view.setTag(tagvalue)**

`button1.setTag(1);`

To get the Tag for a view call the **view.getTag()**

```
button1.getTag();
```