# How I get each of edittext value when I addView the edittext to form?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a button that when I clicked it, the form will add more *edittext* on the form (I'm using *addView*). It is like an order form when I need to 'add more item'.

When I clicked Save button, how can I get all the edittext value?

```
View moreItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_item, (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearItem), false);
final LinearLayout linearForm = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearItem);
linearForm.addView(moreItem);
```

The edit text is inside the R.layout.add_item

Comment: Can you post your code, how you are adding editext using addView?

Comment: I guess, you have to assign Tag to your editext and get those values when required. refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283731/how-to-set-tag-on-a-button-programmatically

Comment: have you solved this?, If yes then please answer your own question, it will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

As you are adding `editText` through `addView()` to a parent view, You can get all the editText value by running a loop. Inside submit button clickListener, add the following code:

```
int count = parentLayout.getChildCount();
String[] editTextValues = new String[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View view = parentlayout.getChildAt(i);          
        if (view instanceof EditText) {
            EditText edittext = (EditText) view;
            editTextValues[i] = editText.getText().toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but we shouldn't get values like this. Suppose he added 5..10 editext and all field contains some text, then how he will differentiate those text message. That's why I asked him for code, where we can see how he used addView()

Comment: He can use `HashMap` & use key values to differentiate between each `editText`s. Let's see what is the op's requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all responses.

I make a `clickcount` variable to count every add more button is clicked.
I have solved this problem with

```
editText.setTag("et"+clickcount); //When I add more button
```

and do a for loop

```
for (int i = 1; i <= clickcount; i++) {
   editText= resultView.findViewWithTag("et"+i);
   String text= editText.getText().toString();
}
```

Thanks **jitesh mohite** for the Idea using getTag()

Answer (score -1):

```
declare  array list
```

final List edittext = new ArrayList<>();
 Button addbutton;
  store each value in list and retrive where you want

```
      addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
         final LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(classname.this);
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            final EditText edt1 = new EditText(classname.this);
            edt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
       edittext.add(edt2);
```

}}

Comment: declare linear  layout in xml file as a container for dynamically created view and add linear layout to container in button click function